# How to iterate over multiple arrays in a JSON object in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, multidimensional-array, components

What I'm trying to do is display both modules but I'm receiving a type error of "mod" undefined. Here's an over few on how I'm passing everything down. Something else I noticed as well was when I passed both modules and mod into components modules will be defined when mod isn't. If I switch mod and modules around then mod will be defined and not modules? Not sure why that happens.

Here's my JSON:

```
enter code here[
{
    "title": "Favorite Sports",
    "itemList": [
        {
            "key": "Her sports",
            "modules": [
                {"label": "BaseBall", "value": "checked"},
                {"label": "Volleyball"}

            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "His sports",
            "mod": [
                {"label": "Soccer"},
                {"label": "Football"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Here's an idea how I'm using my components:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import SystemListData from '../src/data.json'
import Component1 from './Component1';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        systemList: []
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
  const systemList = SystemListData;
  this.setState({
    systemList
  })
}
  render() {
    const { systemList } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {systemList.map((system, index) => {
          return <div key={index}><Component1 itemList={system.itemList} /></div>
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
  
}

export default App;
```

Next:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import React from 'react'
import Component2 from './Component2'

const Component1 = ({itemList}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {itemList.map((item, index) => {
                return <Component2 key={index} header={item.key} modules={item.modules} mod={item.mod} />
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Component1

import React from 'react'
import Component3 from './Component3'

const Component2 = ({ header, modules, mod }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {header}
            <Component3 modules={modules} mod={mod} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Component2

import React from 'react'

const Component3
 = ({ modules, mod }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {modules.map((module, index) => {
                return <div key={index} className=""><input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={module.value} /><label className="ml-2">{module.label}</label></div>
            })}
            {mod.map((module, index) => {
                return <div key={index} className=""><input type="checkbox" /><label className="ml-2">{module.label}</label></div>
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Component3
```

Currently stuck any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need any explanation, or this is not what you are asking about, please comment on my answer

**Short Answer:**

in the array be sure always you have the same name of the key (mod or modules) use 1 of them (let say modules)

then go to each component and delete the mod from it (even if it is in the props or the render)

**Long Answer:**

OK so the problem you have is passing undefined
1) you got this array an store it in the state   (App component)

```
this.state={
  itemList : [
    {
      key: 'Her sports',
      modules: [{ label: 'BaseBall', value: 'checked' }, { label: 'Volleyball' }]
    },
    {
      key: 'His sports',
      mod: [{ label: 'Soccer' }, { label: 'Football' }]
    }
  ]
}
```

2) you pass this array to (Component1)

Component1.props.itemList

TILL NOW EVERYTHING GOOD BUT THE PROBLEM START FROM HERE

3) you iterate over itemList (from props of Component1) and take from it (mod, modules) for each element to Component2 so for example:

itemList[0] has modules but didn't has mod (undefined)

itemList[1] has mod but didn't has modules (undefined)

4) you pass them (mod, modules) from Component2 to Component3 (dont forget we have undefined)

5) in Component3 you iterate over (mod, modules) using map so it is like you say
  undefined.map(.....) and that's why you get the error